# Multi-Layer EXR and Cycles Nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I've used a multi-layer EXR to stash a Mist Pass, along with others. To test it, I've used it in a Displacement modifier on a subdivided plane. The Texture tab allows me to select the relevant layer, and everything works as expected.

But if I try to use the Image data-block in a Cycles Image Texture node, I have no access to the layers, and all I get is missing-texture-magenta. This seems inconsistent. Am I missing something? Can I somehow reach the texture I successfully created for the displacement from a Cycles node-tree? I'd like not to have to split my EXR's up to use them in Cycles nodes.. maybe it's a format problem?

(Version: 2.79b)